# How to drag and drop the polygons in a canvas when drawing the polygon dynamically using mouse clicks?

Tags: javascript, html

How do you drag and drop the polygons in a canvas when you draw the polygon dynamically using mouse clicks using JavaScript with HTML? I tried:

```
<div class="draggable">
    <button id=done hidden>Click when done assigning points>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=450 height=450 class="draggable"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the coordinates in a js variable and redraw the polygon on the canvas on mouse clicks.

Example with squares: http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes